# Getting the pressed key regardless of the keyboard locale?

Tags: keyboard, locale, capture

Let's say I pressed "=" on my English keyboard. If I switch my keyboard language to Turkish, pressing the same key gives me a "-". So I am easly able to say that my operation system interprets the key presses.

My question is, is it possible to get the a key's real value so that no matter which language is used, I can know which key is pressed? Later, I need to use this value(s) with RegisterHotKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use virtual key codes, vs keyboard scan codes which are language dependant.

You didn't specify a programming language, but these should be independant of language and OS. [Virtual-Key Codes link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Since only possible solution will be using a Windows API, no matter which language the answer is in, I (hopefuly) can understand it. What I need is a keyboard scan codes returning API according to your answer.